# c++ get unique values in set and map containers

Tags: c++

How can I get unique values in container?
I see there is `unique()` for vector and list, but I can't find anything similar for set and map.

UPD: I use this to generate values in container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <map>


using namespace std;
template <class T>
void rvec(T& t, int l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)t.push_back(rand() % 10);
}
template <class T>
void rlist(T &t, int l){
  for(int i=0;i<l;i++)t.push_back(rand()%10);
}
template <class T>
void rmset(T &t, int l){
  for(int i=0;i<l;i++)t.insert(rand()%10);
}
template <class T>
void rmap(T &t, int l){
  for(int i=0;i<l;i++)t[i]=rand()%10;
}
template <class T>
void show(T& t) {
    for (auto element : t)cout << element << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
template <class T>
void showmap(T &t){
  for(auto element:t)cout<<element.second<<" ";
  cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    list<int> l;
    multiset<int> s;
    map<int,int> m;

    int num = 30;
    int rtd = rand() % 10;

    rvec(v, num);
    rlist(l, num);
    rmset(s, num);
    rmap(m, num);

    show(v);
    show(l);
    show(s);
    showmap(m);
    cout << endl;

    auto last = unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.resize(distance(v.begin(), last));
    l.unique();
    //something for list
    //something for map

    show(v);
    show(l);
    show(s);
    showmap(m);
    return 0;
}
```

after launching I got

`0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9` for set and

`2 9 2 0 7 2 6 0 8 5 5 1 9 0 3 1 9 3 0 5 3 0 9 3 1 7 2 2 0 7` for map

Comment: The values in a `std::set` are automatically unique. The same is true for the keys in a `std::map`.

Comment: I am creating container with random elements, so they are not

Comment: Show the code then...

Comment: @Mbroo whether the values are random or not is irrelevant. Please share the code that you are concerned about.

Comment: I'd also point out that, assuming you meant `std::unique()`, it's not just for `std::vector` and `std::list`; it can 'eliminate' (move past the new 'end') unique elements from any container that provides usable iterators. Not that there would be any point using it here, at least as written, hence why you need to contextualise the question, otherwise it seems tautological

Comment: If you add an element to a `std::set`, that is already contained, it will not be added again.

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How are you calling those functions? How are you printing out the results you get?

Comment: That's not enough. Show how those functions are called and what the arguments passed are

Comment: added full code

Comment: Your question says you're printing out a set and a map. But your code is printing out a `multiset` (which can have duplicates), and the values of a `map` (which can also be repeated).

Comment: You are talking about map and set, **but**:  1.) multiset can contain values multiple times (it's called _multi_ set for a reason) and 2.) you print only the _values_ of the map. Of course multiple keys can contain the same value, the _keys_ of a map are uniqe.

Comment: sow how to make values unique?

Comment: `v.resize(distance(v.begin(), last));` - this is unnecessarily dependent on the type of container and the fact that it has any notion of size. Instead, use the erase-remove idiom: `v.erase(last, v.end());`. That can work with any container that can `erase`, so pretty much all of them.

Answer (score 3):

> c++ get unique values in set

All values in set are unique, at least in respect to the comparison function.

If you need uniqueness in respect to another comparison function `f2`, then copy the elements from the input set into another set that uses `f2`. Alternatively, copy the elements into a vector (any sequential container would be OK, but arrays are simple and typically fast), then sort and use `std::unique`.

Solutions described in previous paragraph work for map and multiset as well: Copy the elements into a set and you're all done. Or copy them into a vector, and then apply the algorithms.